# i want to move an dialog of an external app to top of the tablet

Tags: android, api, sdk, dialog

Another app pop up a dialog in the center of my tablet suddenly and make my app not visible. Is there any way I can send any kind of api (like what we do in Windows ) to move (and also resize) it to the edges of the tablet but not close it? 
And is it possible to close it also?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using your Application and suddenly, you gets a popup on top of it which is being called from a different application. Basically, there is no way an application can interrupt another until there is permissions provided to the concerned Application.
However, You can check the logs and accordingly you can write a piece of code to dismiss any popup that appears on the screen, but for resizing an popup, I am not sure how to handle the UI.

Thanks!